# JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean to bypass SSL checks

Tags: spring, soap, cxf, spring-remoting

I have an Spring Proxy as a client to access some WS:

```
<bean id="clientPort" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
     <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.acme.IClient"/>
     <property name="serviceName" value="sercie"/>
     <property name="endpointAddress" value="https://com.acme.IService"/>
     <!-- ... -->
</bean>   


 <bean id="client" class="com.acme.Client">
    <property name="theClientPort" ref="clientPort"/>    
</bean>
```

Since it runs in JBoss, i know it uses CXF, now i want to bypass SSL checks, presumably with a HttpConduit, but i cannot setup system variables nor affect the configuration for the rest of CXF clients.

If i could access the object in code i would setup the HttpConduit, but  `((Advised) proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget()` returns null, (maybe i'm missing some configuration in web.xml)